# Эффективность создание несколько классов в одном приложении

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

**1.Вариант**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui


class RightFrame(QtWidgets.QFrame):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        box_right = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.label_choice = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label_choice.setText('Просто текст')
        box_right.addWidget(self.label_choice, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setLayout(box_right)


class Menu(QtWidgets.QMenuBar):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        file_menu = self.addMenu('File')
        close_file = QtWidgets.QAction('Закрыть программу', self)
        close_file.setStatusTip('Close test file')
        close_file.triggered.connect(sys.exit)
        file_menu.addAction(close_file)


class MainWindows(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setFixedSize(600, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle('Test')
        self.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Times New Roman', 35))
        self.setMenuBar(Menu())
        self.setCentralWidget(RightFrame())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ma = MainWindows()
    ma.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**2 Вариант**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui


class MainWindows(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setFixedSize(600, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle('Test')
        self.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Times New Roman', 35))
        self.frame_main_windows()
        self.menu_bar()

    def menu_bar(self):
        menu_bar = self.menuBar()
        file_menu = menu_bar.addMenu('File')

        close_file = QtWidgets.QAction('Закрыть программу', self)
        close_file.setStatusTip('Close test file')
        close_file.triggered.connect(lambda: self.close())
        file_menu.addAction(close_file)

        self.statusBar()

    def frame_main_windows(self):
        self.right_main_frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.right_main_frame)
        box_right = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()

        self.label_choice = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.label_choice.setText('Просто текст')

        box_right.addWidget(self.label_choice, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.right_main_frame.setLayout(box_right)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ma = MainWindows()
    ma.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

На сколько эффективно, правильно, лучше использовать 1 или 2 вариант в написании объемного приложения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Я думаю 1 вариант больше похож на питон.

Если возникнут ошибки в первом листинге их будет гораздо проще исправить.*

Answer (score 1):

С точки зрения простоты сопровождения и вклад в будущее вашего проекта, если он будет развиваться (количество модулей будет расти),  то необходимо выбирать вариант 1. Советую прочитать "Чистый код", Р. Мартин,  достаточно много рассказал про рефакторинг и о том, как стоит писать код.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее второй чем первый, так как это намного проще. Зачем делать класс в котором есть только конструктор, для подобных задач достаточно обычной функции.

Comment: @Lugovtsov Старайся писать ответ более полно.